# Ajax multiple dropdown return value- php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autofill

i had 4 table like this

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o7yS.png)

And then im going to fill this form

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSVRW.png)

the workflow is, when i select **Item Type** and **Treatment**, the price should be filled based on the **ServicePrice Table**, I can get the **Price** from **ServicePrice**, but when I check XHR on network, it shows the value of **Price** but its data just show for 1st time, I mean when the modal opened, it shows the first data, when the option changed, the **Price** value keep like the 1st time modal open. so I want whenever the **Item Type** or **Treatment** changed, I want to make the price box filled dynamically

here's my form

```
<tr>
    <td>Item Type</td>
    <td>
        <select name="ItemTypeID"  class="form-control"  id="ItemType" >
            <option selected=""></option>
            <?php 
            $sql2 = mysql_query("select * from itemtype");
            while($record = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $record['ID']; ?>" title="<?php echo $record['DefaultSpec']; ?>"> <?php echo $record["Name"]; ?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Treatment</td>
    <td>
        <select name="TreatmentID" class="form-control" id="Treatment">
            <?php 
            $sql2 = mysql_query("select * from treatment");
            while($record = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $record['ID']; ?>"> <?php echo $record["Name"]; ?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and then my ajax

```
$("#ItemType, #Treatment").change(function(){ 
    var ItemType = $(this).val();
    var Treatment = $(this).val(); 
    console.log(Treatment);
    console.log(ItemType);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "html",
        url: "GetPrice.php", 
        data: {ItemTypeID: ItemType, TreatmentID: Treatment}, 
        success: function(result){ 
        console.log(result);
        $("#Price").val(result); 
    });
});
```

my GetPrice.php

```
<?php include "../Content/connection.php"; 

$a="SELECT * FROM ServicePrice WHERE ItemtypeID = '".$_POST["ItemTypeID"]."' AND TreatmentID = '".$_POST["TreatmentID"]."'";
$q=mysql_query($a);
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo $record['Price'];
}
?>
```

EDIT :

im making it like this it give me correct answer but the Price value triggered only if treatment dropdown changed, how can i make it trigger by booth dropdown?

```
 $("#ItemType").change(function(){ 
  var ItemType = $(this).val(); 
$("#Treatment").change(function(){ 
  var Treatment = $(this).val();
```

Comment: check in the console if you find any error there? after changing the itemtype and treatment

Comment: one more thing I found in your code is you have taken $(this).val() for both change, so the thing is once you change the ItemType it will assign the same id to both of the variables, and after that you are going to change treatment which means again change the value of both the variable, which means the result you are getting is the same treatmentid and type id which is totally wrong.

Comment: what are you getting in the ajax `console.log(result);`

Comment: @Prateik it say the itemtype and treatment and the Price, but if i change the option, the treatment result will follow the itemtype value. 
 yes i mean that thing, it changed to itemtype and following on it. yeah i know that's my problem, then how can i make it dynamic?

Comment: @devsourav i got the correct Price value. buat cant change the selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `$(this).val()` inside the change event handler will not work to get data for both the fields,
instead fetch the data of **ItemType** and **Treatment** individually

```
$("#ItemType, #Treatment").on('change', function(){
    var ItemType = $("#ItemType").val();
    var Treatment = $("#Treatment").val(); 

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetPrice.php", 
        data: {ItemTypeID: ItemType, TreatmentID: Treatment}, 
        success: function(result){ 
            $("#Price").val(result); 
        }
    });
});
```